# Add Dumpfile Into My Table

Tags: mysql

I wanna restore my dump file (created with mysqldump)if i  restore my dump file into my table,my old data in my table will remove ?
 or dump file add to old data?

Answer (score 0):

**By default `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename` statements are generated** and placed before each `CREATE TABLE ...` statement. You can simply look into your dump file, it's plain text (if not compressed), and see if there are similar lines.

If those statements are there, your data will get deleted and then freshly inserted.

If they are **not** there, you will most likely generate errors by restoring your dump, since duplicate primary keys collide. So usually you will want to go for above mentioned statements.